# vert.x testing with TestNg

Tags: java, testng, webclient, vert.x, junit5

i am new to vert.x , i am trying to make unit testing by calling my webservices . 
i need an example of testing webservices with testng.

when i did it with junit5 it works fine with the below code

```
@BeforeMethod
private static void deploy_verticle(Vertx vertx , VertxTestContext testContext) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle(), testContext.completing());
}


@Test
public void getTestFalse(Vertx vertx , VertxTestContext testContext) throws InterruptedException {
    Assert.assertTrue("3".contains("tesdfsdf"));

    req = new HttpRequestEntityTest();
    req.setHost("localhost");
    req.setPort(8089);
    req.setUri("/api/data");
    utilTest = new RestUtilTest();
    response = new HttpResponseEntityTest();
    utilTest.getTestUtil(req, testContext.succeeding(response -> {
        testContext.verify(() -> {
            Assert.assertTrue(response.getBodyStr().contains("tesdfsdf"));

        });
        testContext.completeNow();

    }));
}


@AfterMethod
public void finish(Vertx vertx , VertxTestContext testContext) {

context.getVertx().close(context.getTestContext().succeeding(response -> {
    context.getTestContext().completeNow();
}));
}
```

but when i try to work with TestNg like this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    public void getTestIqvia() throws InterruptedException {
        Future<HttpResponseEntityTest> future = Future.future();
        response = new HttpResponseEntityTest();
        req = new HttpRequestEntityTest();
        req.setHost("localhost");
        req.setPort(8089);
        req.setUri("/api/data");
        utilTest = new RestUtilTest();

        utilTest.getTestUtil(req, response -> {
            System.out.println(response.result().getBodyStr());

            System.out.println(response.result().getBodyStr().contains("dsds"));
            Assert.assertTrue(response.result().getBodyStr().contains("fdsfds"));

        });
```

GetTestUtil Function :

```
public Future<HttpResponseEntityTest> getTestUtil(HttpRequestEntityTest req,
        Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponseEntityTest>> resultHandler) {
    future = Future.future();

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    response = new HttpResponseEntityTest();
    client.get(req.getPort(), req.getHost(), req.getUri()).send(ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {

            response.setStatusCode(ar.result().statusCode());
            response.setBodyStr(ar.result().bodyAsString());
            future.complete(response);
            System.out.println("Received response with status code get" + response.getStatusCode());
            resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(response));

        } else {
            response.setErrorMsg(ar.cause().getMessage());
            System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
            future.complete(response);

        }

    });

    return future;

}
```

always sending to web client not entered in the arrow function ar and always test success because it doesn't go to Assert function . except fewtimes in debugging mode only

can any one has ana example in testNG with Vert.x?? or what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `getTestIqvia` completes before the `WebClient` callback is invoked.

With jUnit5, the corresponding Vert.x test extension makes sure the test is not marked as passed until all the asynchronous assertions pass.

With TestNG you need to do this manually. In practice, you need to make the test wait until the future returned by `getTestUtil` is completed.

Comment: can you give me an example of doing this ?  i tried to make awaitResult as this :" awaitResult(h ->client.get(req.getPort(), req.getHost(), req.getUri()).send(ar -> { " and in the test class as this "  vertx.eventBus().consumer("read", Sync.fiberHandler(m -> m.reply(utilTest.getTestUtil(req))));
 " ,,,,, and i put @Suspendable in test function

Comment: it gives me this exception >>>>>> QUASAR WARNING: Assertions enabled. This may harm performance.
QUASAR WARNING: Quasar Java Agent isn't running. If you're using another instrumentation method you can ignore this message; otherwise, please refer to the Getting Started section in the Quasar documentation.
FAILED: getTestIqvia
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not in context
 at io.vertx.ext.sync.Sync.getContextScheduler(Sync.java:124)